# Why is SQL Server not scripting all 'relationships' for a given table?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table, say TableA, in a SQL Server database that has multiple 'relationships', in some relationships TableA is the primary key table while in others TableA is the foreign key table.
When I script this table either using 'Script table -> as Create to' or 'Generate scripts' option, SQL Server only generates scripts for relationships where TableA is the foreign key table.

Comment: "relationships" are really just FK constraints - and FK constraints only exist in the table that contains the FK columns (the "dependent" table): not the "principal" table - which makes sense given that FK constraints don't actually constrain the principal table, only the dependent table.

Comment: @Dai Conceptually they actually do constrain the parent table as you cannot delete parent rows if child rows would be orphaned (unless you use cascade). I agree the declaration itself is done on the child table not the parent though.

Comment: @Charlieface Yep - I should have clarified that as _"FK constraint don't constrain the *values* in the principal table..."_ - on a related tangent, I do find it odd that FK constraints are the _only_ cross-table constraints that exist in every RDBMS out there - I don't know why we don't have "anti-FK" constraints - or why no-one supports ISO SQL's _assertions_ - but I could go on...

Comment: @Dai If you ever have a need for weird multi-table constraints in SQL Server https://dbfiddle.uk/iRIliRpX

Comment: @Charlieface [Right on](https://spaghettidba.com/2011/08/03/enforcing-complex-constraints-with-indexed-views/) - but any idea how we can feasibly have a non-unique FK? e.g. given tables `Books` and `Authors`, adding a new table: `PublishedAuthors`  (i.e. `Authors` with at least 1 `Book`) - normally `PublishedAuthors` would just be a `VIEW`, but what if we want to have an FK from a fourth table `BookSigningTours` to `PublishedAuthors` - I'm unsure how that could be done...

Comment: @Dai Yeah you'd need triggers https://dbfiddle.uk/3Qe8zoph

Comment: Make `Book(BookId,AuthorId)` a primary or alternate key, then BookSigningTours and/or PublishedAuthors can have a FK targeting this key on Book.